# Find numbers of monotonically increasing Sub-array

Tags: java, arrays

Given the array, i need to find how many monotonically increasing Sub-arrays there are in that array?

For example, with [0, 1, 3, 1 , 2] - has 2 monotonical sub-arrays : [0, 1,3] and [1,2].

```
public class SUB_ARRAY {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        int[] x = new int[6];
        x[0]=1;
        x[1]=2;
        x[2]=3;
        x[3]=6;
        x[4]=9;
        x[5]=10;
        ArrayList<Object> arraylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
        HashSet list = new HashSet();
        for ( int i=0; i< (x.length -1); i++){
            if (x[i+1]> x[i] ){
                list.add(x[i]);
                list.add(x[i+1]);

            } else if (x[i+1] < x[i] || x[i+1]==x[i]) {
                arraylist.add(list.clone());    
                list.clear();    
            }
        }    
        System.out.println(arraylist.size());

    }    
}
```

The output is : 0 (instead of 1).

So, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a HashSet (and why give it the name "list"?)? Why the ArrayList? Why not just use a simple counter variable? And why after 108 posts here is  your code formatted all left-justified?

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels : HashSet -  cause duplicated integer is not allowed, just the wrong name.. ArrayList to count numbers of HashSet. Sorry about the format..

Comment: @TU_HEODAKAI:  you don't need HashSet or ArrayList. Just iterate through your array with a for loop and check if the number is greater than the one previous to it. Just use a simple counter variable. You're making this much more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: @TU_HEODAKAI: your example is not correct.
For example, with [0, 1, 3, 1 , 2] - has 4 monotonical sub-arrays : [0, 1], [0,1,3], [1,3] and [1,2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this solution. It now only displays the counter but print you the subarrays. If you need only the continues subarrays you can easily modify it.
As you see I use neither HashSet nor ArrayList for storing temporary data just a counter.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SUB_ARRAY{
    public static int SUBARRAY_MINIMUM_LENGTH = 2;
    public static void main(String a[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x.add(5);
        x.add(0);
        x.add(1);
        x.add(3);
        x.add(4);
        x.add(2);
        x.add(3);
        x.add(6);
        x.add(1);
        x.add(0);
        x.add(4);
        int monoton = 0;
        int changed = -1;
        System.out.println("Initial array: " + x.toString());
        for ( int i=0; i< x.size() -1; ++i){
            if (x.get(i+1) > x.get(i)){
                if (changed > -1){
                    for (int j = changed; j <i+2; ++j){
                        monoton += checkSubArray(x, j, i+2);;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("New monoton subarray start index: " + i + " value: " + x.get(i));
                    changed = i;
                    monoton += checkSubArray(x, changed, i+2);
                }
            }
            else if (changed > -1){
                changed = -1;
            }
        }    
        System.out.println("Monoton count: " + monoton);
    }    

    private static int checkSubArray(ArrayList<Integer> x, int start, int end)
    {
        if (end-start < SUBARRAY_MINIMUM_LENGTH){ 
            return 0;
        }
        for (int subi = start; subi < end; ++subi){
            System.out.print(" " + x.get(subi));
        }
        System.out.println();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The output will be the following

```
Initial array: [5, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 1, 0, 4]
New monoton subarray start index: 1 value: 0
 0 1
 0 1 3
 1 3
 0 1 3 4
 1 3 4
 3 4
New monoton subarray start index: 5 value: 2
 2 3
 2 3 6
 3 6
New monoton subarray start index: 9 value: 0
 0 4
Monoton count: 10
```

Comment: Please try to understand the code not just copy+use it if it's OK for you.